# How to edit existing place with Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I am working for a business that deals with auto body shops - we have them subscribed to a service and want to enhance that service by utilizing the Goolge Places API.

I would like to update the places entries by adding or changing specific photos, descriptions and contact info.  I realize there is a section of the documentation that deals with adding a 'place report' but I felt this flow was unclear and/or ambiguous.

In other words, what happens when i place this report?  Is there a vetting process that only google is involved in?  Does this even do what I'm asking it to do?  Is this creating a new entry entirely?

Any help on clarification is appreciated.  I may have missed the obvious here so if you feel that way let me know with a link please.

Comment: You should Hire Someone, if You Don't Know How to Program. This Website is to Help Programmers, Not Business Owners. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

Comment: It seems like you did not read my question.  See, clearly I know where the documentation is located, as I have mentioned that in my post.  See the question is actually *about* the documentation, you donkey's ass.  And, I am not the owner of the business, as I have *already stated above*, I am working for the business that provides a b2b service.  Please troll somewhere else.  Anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Places Photo service is a read-only API that allows you to easily add high quality photographic content to your application.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos

Did you not understand the 'read-only' part?

Comment: Nope.  I did not see that.  Sometimes people miss things.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I see that on the photos - how about the places actions?  I can also see that you can add new places - editing, yes DOES SEEM like its only available to businesses using a profile page instead of some kind of 'write' access API - but here I am asking the question in case I missed that.  I was looking for an answer to that overall gist of my question.  Ostensibly looking at the API did give me a 'read-only' feel, yes.  Please let me know if I've overlooked the ability to do what I am asking to do in my OP.  Thanks .... bro.